# g++ Compile error: missing ';'

Tags: g++, compiler-errors, sstream

I am trying to run this code

```
tResults = itos(Freq)+"\t"dtos(maxTemp)+"\t"+dtos(xB * FP.parU[1])+"\t"+dtos(xH * FP.parI[1])+"\t"+dtos(FP.parI[1]);

string MaxResults::itos(int i) 
{
    stringstream s;
    s << i;
    return s.str();
}

string MaxResults::dtos(double i) 
{
    stringstream s;
    s << i;
    return s.str();
}
```

and when I try to compile, g++ tells me

```
 error: expected `;' before ‘dtos’
```

but I don't see where I would need a semicolon in there.  Is there a concept that I'm missing, or am I just an idiot?

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of just using a single stream?

Comment: Maybe a bit overambitious in hoping to maintain single liners like this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tResults = itos(Freq)+"\t"dtos(maxTemp)

Missing a plus between the tab and dtos(maxTemp)...

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `+` after the first `"\t"`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the first line: `"\t"dtos(maxTemp)` is missing a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `+` in front of the first `dtos`

```
//                    vvvvvvvv
tResults = itos(Freq)+"\t"dtos(maxTemp)+"\t"+dtos(xB * FP.parU[1])+"\t"+dtos(xH * FP.parI[1])+"\t"+dtos(FP.parI[1]);
```

By the way, how is `tResults` declared? Are you sure, that you know what this row does?